# Get input type in Geb

Tags: geb

I am using Geb to write a script that will test a survey many times with random input to make sure nothing breaks.  I would like to iterate through every input on a form and do different things depending on the input type.

For example:

```
while ($("form").find("input", j)) {
    if($("form").find("input", j) == "checkbox"){
        //check it sometimes
    }
    else if($("form").find("input", j) == "select"){
        //select a random option
    }
    j++
}
```

I'm not exactly sure how the survey is going to work yet, so I would rather go down the page as a human would instead of doing all checkboxes first and then all selects etc.  It is possible to check the type of input like my example?

Additionally, I notice I am repeating the $("form").find("input", j).  Can I make that into a variable like in jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply collect all your `input`s and `select`s in a navigator and iterate over all of them. Use `is(String tagName)` to detect select elements and `@type` attribute accessor to detect other element types:

```
def form = $("form")
def formElements = form.find("input") + form.find("select")
formElements.each { Navigator element ->
    if (element.is("select") {
        //select a random option
    }
    if (element.@type == "checkbox") {
        //check it sometimes
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Can I change the value of elements in the formElements list like this?  `element = somevalue`

Comment: No, you will need to use the [`value(Object)` method on `Navigator`](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/api/geb/navigator/Navigator.html#value(def)) in the following way: `element.value(someValue)`

Comment: @erdi: How to use the iterator() to iterate over elements?

Comment: The answer shows one way of doing so by using the `each` method.

Comment: @erdi: Thank you very much for the solution above. It helped me. Can you help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504743/spock-iteratig-over-a-naviator-object